# Прозрачное проксирование с разными параметрами

Tags: linux, proxy

Нужно исполнять определенную команду, для примера `ping` через *socks5*.

Сразу нужно выполнять несколько приложений через разные соксы.

Например, через *SOCKS5* 192.168.1.10 выполнить `ping`, и через 192.168.1.20 выполнить `ping`.

Хотелось бы что-то вроде:

```
[programname] -socks 192.168.1.10 "ping google.com"
[programname] -socks 192.168.1.20 "ping google.com"
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: непонятно, перепишете вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

скрипт `parallel-ping.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
for address in "192.168.1.10" "192.168.1.20"
do {
    echo "server = $address" > $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    echo "server_port = 1080" >> $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    tsocks ping $*
  } &
done
wait
```

а так запускаем:

```
$ parallel-ping.sh google.com
```

подойдёт?

---

**обновление**

приведённый выше скрипт не будет работать так, как ожидается: одновременно запущенные команды `echo ...` создадут в файле `~/.tsocks.conf` «кашу».

последовательное же выполнение набора команд — вполен работоспособно. только ещё неплохо бы добавить ограничение в виде количества отсылаемых пакетов — чтобы `ping`-и не «висели» вечно.

примерно так:

```
#!/bin/bash
for address in "192.168.1.10" "192.168.1.20"
do
    echo "server = $address" > $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    echo "server_port = 1080" >> $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    tsocks ping -c 3 $*
done
```

Comment: Конечно же я забыл, что пинги не ходят через прокси, ещё я заметил, что скрипт на моей текущей версии tsocks (1.8beta5-9.2) вызывает ошибку `libtsocks: SOCKS server <сервер> is not on a local subnet!` поэтому предлагаю чуть изменённое решение, использующее httping ниже.

Answer (score 0):

Чуть изменённое решение, использующее httping.

```
#!/bin/bash
for address in "server1" "server2" 
do {
    echo "server = $address" > $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    echo "server_port = 1080" >> $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    echo "local = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0" >> $HOME/.tsocks.conf
    tsocks httping $*
  } &
done
wait
```